# 403 Forbidden Access to this resource on the server is denied! en Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

Monte mi aplicación laravel en mi hosting. Ahi tengo una pagina en wordpress alojada en el directorio principal public_html.

Mi aplicación laravel esta en public_html/laravel y tengo mi dominio dominio.com apuntando a public_html/laravel/public

Cuando entro a dominio.com me carga perfectamente la web de bienvenida de laravel (view welcome.blade.php). Pero cuando quiero acceder a un formulario que tengo en la funcion create de mi controlador en la ruta dominio.com/participantes/create obtengo un:

403 Forbidden Access to this resource on the server is denied! en Laravel 5.8

Mi archivo .htaccess dentro de ...laravel/public es:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Y mis rutas laravel:

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('participantes', 'ParticipanteController');
```

Comment: como están los permisos de la carpeta storage/ y boopstrap/? Por otra parte ejecutaste `php artisan key:generate`?

Comment: Si, ejecute ese comando. Al final tuve que borrar la carpeta completa de la aplicación en el hosting, subir la que tenia en local y volvio a funcionar.